# Python put requests on a CIRCUITPY

Tags: python, python-requests, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a CIRCUITPY macro board (keybow 2040) that I want to make automatically download a file, but I don't have enough storage space on the board to put all the required libraries for the python requests module.
The board's available storage space is 866 KB, which is not nearly enough storage space for all the required modules to use requests.

Is there any smaller version of requests that can just get the content of an address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like CircuitPython has its own requests-like library, in the module `adafruit_requests`: https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/requests/en/latest/index.html

Comment: So I tried this, and I used the example py file and the pins are incorrect because I have a keybow 2040 (sorry I didn't specify before) and I can't find a way to use different pins.

Comment: the code that triggered the error was: `spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, board.MOSI, board.MISO)`

Comment: @susthebus I don't know anything about CircuitPython, but that's probably a better question for their forums or Discord channel